# How to find the actual line numbers of the errors I'm getting with TOAD 10.6.1.3?

Tags: plsql, toad

Whenever I compile my PLSQL code in TOAD 10.6.1.3, it refers to incorrect line numbers.  I am using TOAD 10.6.1.3 , does anyone know what causes this ?

Comment: Did you try to format code first (select all, press Ctrl + Shift + F), then compile (F9)? Any improvement?

Comment: Please edit your question and add examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle errors indicate the line numbers in the package source code. If your text editor is not showing the source *exactly* as compiled, the line numbers might not align.

You may find that using the schema browser to view the contents of your package will show the correct line numbers.

Alternatively, you can query `USER_SOURCE` or `ALL_SOURCE` to view the package source; the column `LINE` has the line numbers.